# split string between 2 char based index

Tags: android, string, kotlin, split

How can we split a text between two char in Kotlin?

Example string:

```
base_id:94, user_id: 320903, is_Active=1
```

I want to get only user_id so "320903". But I couldn't do that.

Comment: Where exactly is that string coming from? The format looks pretty inconsistent here (`:` vs `=`, whitespace etc.). It seems like it wants to look like JSON without being JSON. You can definitely parse it with substrings, but the stability of the format should be considered if you're going to do that

Comment: @Joffrey thanks for comment. Unfortunately  I can't change this bad format. Yes I can use subString() but user_id digit can be changed. I try to get this string by finding the id between second ':' and second ','. It will work but I cant do it.

Comment: Btw, is you user_id always of 6 digits?

Comment: @ArpitShukla no digit can be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get it is using regex and you can customize it to cover base_id and is_Active

```
val pattern = Pattern.compile("user_id: (?<id>[0-9]+)")
val matcher = pattern.matcher(text)
if (matcher.find()) {
    val group = matcher.group("id").trim()
    println(group)
}
```

The output will be : `320903`

Or you can do that with split only and you will get the same result

```
val items = text.split(",")
val userId = items[1].split(":")[1].trim()
println(userId)
```

That will work correctly with your example but make sure but for other cases, you may need to customize it or give us many examples to cover them

You can handle the 3 values with one function that support optional whitespace and : or =

```
fun getValueByTagName(text : String, tag : String) : String {
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("$tag[:=][ ]*(?<id>[0-9]+)")
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(text)
    return if (matcher.find())
        matcher.group("id").trim()
    else ""
}
```

To use it

```
println(getValueByTagName(text, "base_id"))      // 94
println(getValueByTagName(text, "user_id"))      // 320903
println(getValueByTagName(text, "is_Active"))    // 1
```

Comment: The matcher implementation here doesn't make much sense, why not just use the correct group directly instead of taking the whole match (group 0) and split it manually? Also, the OP hasn't yet clarified the format of the string, so this whitespace might be optional, the colon might be a `=` sometimes for all we know

Comment: Yes you are right whitespace might be optional and also = and : because that I said that this solution will work with the example but you we need clear rules to customize it

Comment: thanks. this format is constant. It will be always like this. So according to this second   way is best way?

Comment: Yes the second one is the best and i have added new solution that cover the 3 values if you want it in any time

Comment: @AmrDeveloper I wasn't saying the whole regex approach was wrong. I was saying this specific implementation using `split()` on the whole matched group was wasteful. Using `()` inside the regex and accessing the correct group directly would be better

Comment: @Joffrey Thank you so much for this suggestion, this is my first time using this feature, it is amazing :D, I have edited my answer

Comment: thank you very much guys. This works perfect. In edited answer why we used id value?

Comment: Id because I named this group with id -> `?<id>[0-9]+)` which is the number we wanted, I searched by `Regex Named Groups` for this feature inspired from @Joffrey comment

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

Method 1: If your string has **exactly** the same format that you have shown in the example.

```kotlin
val indexOfUserId = s.indexOf("user_id") // find index of the substring "user_id"
val end = s.indexOf(',', indexOfUserId) // find index of ',' after user_id
val userId s.substring(indexOfUserId + 9, end) // take the substring assuming that userId starts exactly 9 characters after the "u" in "user_id"
```

Method 2: If your format can vary (in spaces and symbols). Also assuming that user_id is always a number.

```kotlin
val indexOfUserId = s.indexOf("user_id")
val start = s.findAnyOf(List(10) { "$it" }, indexOfUserId)!!.first // find the first digit after "user_id"
val userId = s.substring(start).takeWhile { it.isDigit() } // start from the first digit and continue as long as you are getting digits
```

Here, `List(10) { "$it" }` is just a list of all digits in string format and [findAnyOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/find-any-of.html):

> Finds the first occurrence of any of the specified [strings] in this char sequence, starting from the specified [startIndex]

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/bo2Kn6dhk)